# Share local folder over Internet

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, nat

How would I share a folder over the Internet and also have the machine on a LAN? The internet connection has a fixed IP.

The purpose would be to host an Access backend. I know Access doesn't work well in that configuration - I just want to test it for now. I don't want to use a VPN - too inefficient.

If it takes multihoming or a new Internet connection, that's okay.

Comment: Note that by opening it up to the internet you give everyone on the internet to your Access backend too. Also there are a LOT of virus on the internet that all they do is scan for open shares like these and infect all the files they can find on the share. What is "too inefficent" about using a VPN? If you set it up at the router (even consumer grade routers support it with custom firmware like DD-WRT) it could be transparent to the end user and "look like" you are just connecting over the internet but are magnitudes safer.

Comment: So the answer to my question on how to do it is?

Comment: Well you said you don't want to use a VPN, so the only solution you have is port forward like the current answer states and hope your ISP does not block you and a virus does not discover your IP via a port scan and infect all of the files on the share with viruses.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to setup your router/firewall to forward some port from `public_ip` to `private_ip` (private ip of the host hosting the share).

Here are the port to open/forward for a standard Windows share :

- TCP/445
- TCP/139
- UDP/137
- UDP/138

[Source for ports](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731402.aspx)

Tested in my company, it works.
Hope it will help you in your context.

Cheers

Comment: While this may have worked for your company many, many, ISP's block these ports do to the large number of virusus that spread that way.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain: i agree with you and ISP are right (risks are mentionned by Microsoft in the link provided). I'm going to try this at home to see if my ISP block this. Edit : as we are on "super user" i assume that we are talking about a home Network, but not sure...in case we are talking about a corporate Network rules are a little different

Comment: user2196728, the network is is in a small office - basically a home system. That sounds like it should work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The post above is right with the ports, however, if an ISP blocks those ports, you can use a random external port, that points to a different internal port. For example:

123.123.123.123:500 > 192.168.1.6:445

Just make sure that when you try to access your files from outside the network, you use the external address and port. (Obviously)

I'd recommend using FTP or WebDAV, to secure your connection tho. Windows Pro versions come with it built in, you just have to enable and configure it.